# Could not find StateFunctionModule in Example, no routers are defined error

Tags: apache-flink, flink-statefun

I could run Harness example [here](https://github.com/apache/flink-statefun/tree/master/statefun-examples/statefun-flink-harness-example)

but I copied the code to another directory and use the same dependencies in `pom.xml`, it raised error that `no routers defined`

I debug and found that `MyModule` which extends `StateFunModule` was not found. Thus the class loader get no module and the router and func size is 0 and failed in validation step. (The step to check ingress, egress, router, func not size 0)

PS: I just copied all the code, thus `@AutoService` is also included. According to [here](http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Stateful-Functions-java-lang-IllegalStateException-There-are-no-routers-defined-td34624.html#a34711), it should work without further configuration.

---

Update:
Seems its statefun issue related to `@AutoService`

I added following code in the pom in another project (unrelated to statefun)

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auto.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>auto-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-rc6</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

It works, the META-INF is generated.

But if using

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>statefun-flink-distribution</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

The META-INF is not generated, and I found in statefun, the dependency used is actually

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.auto.service</groupId>
            <artifactId>auto-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-rc6</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
```

And I test this dependency, it could not generate META-INF, and I am curious that why if we directly clone the statefun repo and `mvn clean package`, it could work.

Comment: Not sure what's wrong, but maybe having another example will help. You could look at https://github.com/ververica/flink-statefun-workshop.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I think the example with different location and 0 code change should be executed with no difficulty, otherwise the portability of this feature seems bad.

Comment: The problem I ran into when writing a Harness test in flink-statefun-workshop was that I had to use exactly the same version of protobuf that is used in statefun itself, but otherwise it was straightforward. That test is in https://github.com/ververica/flink-statefun-workshop/blob/master/statefun-workshop-functions/src/test/java/com/ververica/statefun/workshop/harness/RunnerTest.java.

Comment: @Litchy can you please validate that indeed your jar contains a META-INF/services/org.apache.flink.statefun.sdk.spi.StatefulFunctionModule and it's content points to your MyModule class?.

Comment: @Igal I think you get the point of it. In example there is correct META-INF, but after I copied it and build, this META-INF is not generated. But who control this operation, do I need extra code in addition to copy and build?

Comment: @Litchy you can include that file manually in your src/main/resources/META-INF/services

Comment: @Igal I create the dir and write the file by myself and it works. Anyway...this is not "auto" enough...